# docker Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Tags: centos, docker, zabbix

I am facing this error with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:latest

ENV container docker
MAINTAINER The CentOS Project <cloud-ops@centos.org>

RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]  

RUN rpm -U https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.0/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-5.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y install zabbix-agent
RUN yum clean all

COPY ./zbx-speedtest.sh /etc/zabbix/bin/zbx-speedtest.sh
RUN chmod +x /etc/zabbix/bin/zbx-speedtest.sh
COPY ./speedtest.conf /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/speedtest.conf

COPY ./zabbix-speedtest.service /etc/systemd/system/zabbix-speedtest.service
COPY ./zabbix-speedtest.timer /etc/systemd/system/zabbix-speedtest.timer

RUN systemctl enable zabbix-speedtest.timer
RUN systemctl enable zabbix-agent.service
RUN systemctl start zabbix-agent.service
RUN systemctl start zabbix-speedtest.timer

CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

When trying to use either `docker-compose` or `docker build` I receive this error:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
ERROR: Service 'zbx' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c systemctl start zabbix-agent.service' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I looked everywhere, nothing is up for a solution. If it is impossible to do that with docker, please tell me which container to learn that can do that?

`zabbix-speedtest.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=Run a speedtest every 5 minutes

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/5
# RandomizedDelaySec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

`zabbix-speedtest.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Run a speedtest
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
#User=zabbix-agent
#User=root
User=zabbix
ExecStart=/etc/zabbix/bin/zbx-speedtest.sh --run
CPUSchedulingPolicy=fifo
CPUSchedulingPriority=80

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Generally docker containers don't have `systemd` running within them.  Maybe try https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/

Comment: Putting an init system inside of a docker container is an anti-pattern.

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: @elekgeek See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980601/what-is-an-anti-pattern#980616). basically, something that you shouldn't do, and if you feel compelled to do it, there is something wrong in your design. In this case, you can run some of your system daemons as containers instead of plain processes (pattern) but running daemons inside your containers is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I don't understand why the courses I came across while trying to learn docker never mentioned this :) You know, I have to try things myself to learn, and ask the experts here who will write some lines that equal 20 hours of training, really.. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I download and run `centos:latest`, it gives me a CentOS 8 Docker container that does not run `systemd`.  You would need to do more to get `systemd` working, but you really should not need an init system since Docker is designed to run a single process inside its containers.

Looking at the [Zabbix Agent Dockerfile produced by Zabbix](https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker/blob/5.0/agent/centos/Dockerfile), it does not try to use `systemd`.

Have you tried to use `zabbix/zabbix-agent:centos-5.0-latest` and see if that works any better?

Update after comments:

This is what your Dockerfile would possibly look like after using these recommendations:

```
FROM zabbix/zabbix-agent:centos-5.0-latest
ENV container docker

COPY ./zbx-speedtest.sh /etc/zabbix/bin/zbx-speedtest.sh
RUN chmod +x /etc/zabbix/bin/zbx-speedtest.sh
COPY ./speedtest.conf /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/speedtest.conf
```

You would then need to adjust `zabbix-speedtest.service` and `zabbix-speedtest.timer` to run from the context of the host you will be deploying the Docker container on.

Comment: I used this container,but I need to run a script using either systemd timer or cron, any idea how I can use cron in zabbix container? Help appreciated, really.. if you look at the Dockerfile i posted in the question, you will see I am trying to run a script, thanks

Comment: Instead of `FROM centos:latest` use `FROM zabbix/zabbix-agent:centos-5.0-latest` and add your script to the container image.  Since `cron` is also another process that is likely not running in your container, it may be best to use `cron` or the `systemd` timer from the host to time your periodic runs.  Maybe you can adapt your `zabbix-speedtest.timer` to run on the host using `docker exec`.

Comment: I am really confused, seems I am thinking the old baremetal way, please guide me with more details how such Dockerfile should be done.

Comment: I updated the answer to add a sample Dockerfile for your use case.  You have not shared the contents of `zabbix-speedtest.service` and `zabbix-speedtest.timer` so I am unable to comment on how you might fix those.

Comment: I added the content for `zabbix-speedtest.timer` and `zabbix-speedtest.service`

Comment: `zabbix-speedtest.timer` looks like it can be deployed to the Docker host without any modification.  In `zabbix-speedtest.service`, you may not have a `zabbix` user on the host and you would change the `ExecStart` to something like `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME /etc/zabbix/bin/zbx-speedtest.sh --run`

Comment: I think I will do two containers, one for zbx-speedtest.sh which will be run every 5 minutes, the other for zabbix agent, and have a directory shared among those containers that contains speedtest.json and that's it. @GracefulRestart Thank you all indeed, your advices and suggestions were truly helpful to how one should think in docker.